# Obtating the Fermi Coupling Constant from expeced muon decay

Tags: particle-physics, dimensional-analysis, si-units, weak-interaction, electroweak

I recently performed a lab where we found the expected muon lifetime as $\tau = 2.02$ microseconds. I am now supposed to use this value to obtain the Fermi Coupling Constant $G_F$, by using the equation:
$$\tau= \frac{192\pi^2\hbar^7}{G_F^2m^5c^4}$$
I was wondering if someone could take a look at my solution and tell me if this makes sense. I started by arranging the equation as follows:
$$G_F=\sqrt{\frac{1}{\tau}\frac{192\pi^2\hbar^7}{m^5c^4}}$$
This is where I start having a problem. I tried calculating $G_F$ by simply plugging in SI units into the previous equation, but this gives me $G_F = 1.5\times10^{-62} \;kg\;m^7\;s^{-1}$.

This is my first time every hearing about the Fermi Coupling Constant or doing anything particle physics related so I'm not really sure if this makes any sense. But to me those units do not really make any sense. When I did some googling I noticed that Fermi Coupling Constant is always given as $G_F/(c\hbar)^3$, why is that?

Comment: I get different units.

Comment: (a) Your formula has a typo, it should be $\pi^3$. (b) The units you quoted are in fact not correct, they should be ${\rm kg\ m^5\ s^{-2}}$. But regardless of this, why do you think the units don't make sense? (c) Have you tried using dimensional analysis to see what units $G_F/(c\hbar)^3$ has? This might give you a hint.

Comment: *why is that?* Because particle physicists like to convert every kind of physical quantity into some power of energy (GeV, GeV$^4$, GeV$^{-2}$, etc.) by multiplying or dividing by powers of $\hbar$ and $c$.

Comment: Related: [Why is the Fermi coupling constant always expressed in units of $(\hbar c)^3$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/148038/why-is-the-fermi-coupling-constant-always-expressed-in-units-of-hbar-c3)